# Cannot use import statement outside a module - Vuex testing quasar

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vuex, quasar-framework

how are you ?

I'm having a issue in testing Vuex stuff with Quasar.

Testing components is working normally, but when I started to test my store, I got it.

spec file:

```
/test/jest/__tests__/store/auth/mutations.spec.js

import { store } from 'src/store';
import { mutations } from 'src/store/auth';
import mutations from 'src/store/auth/mutations';
```

All those ways I tried to import my store stuff, I got this error:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers';

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

how can I import my store in my spec files?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { store } from 'src/store';
import { mutations } from 'src/store/auth';
import mutations from 'src/store/auth/mutations';
```

just use require

```
const store = require('src/store');
const mutations = require('src/store/auth)';
const mutations = require('src/store/auth/mutations');
```

you need 
type=module in package.json to use import

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `import` statements are not supported by plain JavaScript, therefore neither by Node. `import` is an addition called `ES Modules`. Since Jest runs your tests in Node, you are getting `SyntaxError` since `import { store } from 'quasar/wrappers'` is invalid JS syntax.

The solution is that you need to tell Jest to use Babel (or similar tool) to transform your test file before trying to execute it in Node.

This requires some configuration in your `jest.config.js`, and also you'd need to install `babel-jest`, `babel` and related packages and create a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js` to tell Babel what to do with your test files exactly.

The actual right configuration may depend on many factors, but as a starting point refer to these:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel
- https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest#setup

Also I'd recommend to consider using Quasar CLI, which gives you a handy way to automatically set up Jest for your Quasar project, including a simple example test you can use as a starting reference: https://testing.quasar.dev/